# How to create a WPF interactive tour to application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a WPF Windows application and I would like to add in interactive walkthrough in order to help users learn how to use the app.

I want to add something similar to this for a website: http://tourmyapp.com

Is there a way to do this for WPF??

Comment: Yes you can definitely do that with wpf, but you will probably have to write a lot of code because i doubt you will find a library for that

Comment: Dunno if there exists tools to help build such toturial, but it is possible, just like on web can set a z-index and put the turial views on top of your app

Comment: There is actually a library that supports exactly that: [FeatureTour](https://github.com/JanDotNet/ThinkSharp.FeatureTour)!
Disclosure: I am the creator of that library.

Answer (score 4):

I do not know if a specific tool for your purpose exists, but in my opinion you can write your code by your own. It is not so difficult.

You can get ideas from this simple sample. I used the [CallOut](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.expression.controls.callout(v=expression.40).aspx) control - you can find it in the [Microsoft.Expression.Drawing](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Expression.Drawing/) library).

Now let's see the XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow" Name="win"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:ed="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/drawing"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="600">

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Margin="0, 200, 200, 0">
            <TextBox Margin="10" Name="TextBox" />
            <CheckBox Content="Flag" Margin="10" Name="CheckBox"
                      Width="70" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
            <Button Content="Click Me" Margin="10" Name="Button" />
            <ComboBox Margin="10" Name="ComboBox">
                <sys:String>Item 1</sys:String>
                <sys:String>Item 2</sys:String>
                <sys:String>Item 3</sys:String>
            </ComboBox>
            <Button Name="Start" Content="Start Tour" Margin="10" Click="StartTour" />

        </StackPanel>

        <ed:Callout Name="Callout" Fill="LightYellow"
                    Width="200"
                    Height="100"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    CalloutStyle="Oval"
                    Stroke="Black"
                    Visibility="Hidden" Panel.ZIndex="100">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock Name="CalloutMessage" Margin="5" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Button Content="Ok" Click="Ok" Margin="1" />
                    <Button Content="Cancel" Click="Cancel" Margin="1" />
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </ed:Callout>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

I added some sample controls and a button for starting the tour. You can find the `CallOut` too. It will be moved in order to "explain" other controls.

Now in the code-behind we have:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private NameValueCollection tourData = new NameValueCollection();
        private int currentIndex;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            tourData.Add("TextBox", "This is a TextBox");
            tourData.Add("Button", "This is a Button. You can click it");
            tourData.Add("CheckBox", "This is a CheckBox");
            tourData.Add("ComboBox", "This is a ComboBox. You can select an item");

        }

        private void MoveCallout(FrameworkElement element, string message)
        {
            GeneralTransform generaTransform = element.TransformToAncestor(this);
            Point point = generaTransform.Transform(new Point(0, 0));

            double x = point.X + element.ActualWidth + 4;
            double y = point.Y + element.ActualHeight + 4;

            CalloutMessage.Text = message;
            Callout.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(x, y);
        }

        private void StartTour(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            currentIndex = 0;
            Callout.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            Start.IsEnabled = false;

            FrameworkElement element = (FrameworkElement)FindName(tourData.GetKey(currentIndex));
            MoveCallout(element, tourData.Get(currentIndex));

            currentIndex++;
        }

        private void Ok(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            FrameworkElement element;
            if (currentIndex < tourData.Count)
            {
                element = (FrameworkElement)FindName(tourData.GetKey(currentIndex));
                MoveCallout(element, tourData.Get(currentIndex));

                currentIndex++;
            }
            else
            {
                Callout.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
                Start.IsEnabled = true;
            }

        }

        private void Cancel(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            Callout.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
            Start.IsEnabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

This sample is not MVVM compliant of course. Anyway I guess it would not require a great effort to change it in a MVVM way.

I hope this sample can help you and can give you some hint for your work.

Answer (score -3):

You could check out [Whatfix](http://whatfix.com). It is a tool similar to TourMyApp but much easier to use and has a lot of useful features.

With it, you can easily create interactive walkthroughs on any web application seamlessly.

It works across all web applications or website. You can use the Whatfix editor for Chrome or Firefox to create the interactive walkthroughs. Once created, it the walkthroughs can be viewed across all web browsers.